# SPF record for an mail server

Tags: email, dns, text-files, spf, mx-record

I use a different server to send mail to my mailing list. I want to add an SPF record to my domain to show that the IP of the different server is authorized to send mail (as well as the default server).

The server sending email in the example is 1.2.3.4 with the main domain of test.co.uk.

So far I have `v=spf1  mx  a  ip4:1.2.3.4/32  mx:test.co.uk ?all"`, would this work for what I want?

EDIT:
I would be sending mail using sendmail. The SPF record would be to increase % of mail going to inbox and also so we can enforce -all in the near future on SPF.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an online tool like http://www.mtgsy.net/dns/spfwizard.php to generate the SPF record. If you Google for "SPF Record checker", you will find many websites which will even validate the SPF record for your domain.

Comment: thanks for that online tool link, finally my emails are going into inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your domain is test.co.uk. This makes `mx` the same as `mx:test.co.uk`. Specifying an IP as `ip4:1.2.3.4` is the same as `ip4:1.2.3.4/32`.
That would be enough:

```
v=spf1 mx a ip4:1.2.3.4 ?all
```

Make sure you verify your SPF records using a SPF checker. Try the following one.
http://spf.myisp.ch
It does some pretty extensive testing.